# Save generated PDF files in iPad's / iPhone's internal memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm generating PDF files and saving them in my sandbox. May I able to store those PDF files to the iPad's/iPhone's internal memory? Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. Apps on iOS are contained to their sandbox. With few exceptions (like Keychain or Photo Library), it is not possible to access or save resources outside of sandbox.